# double dispatch in swift for numeric types

Tags: swift, numeric, double-dispatch, swift3

Like many people I am trying to work with both integers and floating points and collections of these types.

However the Swift type system is not always that forgivable. Most people define a Numeric protocol to deal with this. I would like to know if there is a better way and how Apple does this.

So:

Integers in Swift come in several types

```
let i1 : Int16 = 6
let i2 : Int32 = 32
let i3 : Int   = 64
```

and we can confirm their types

```
print(i1.dynamicType) //Int16
print(i2.dynamicType) //Int32
print(i3.dynamicType) //Int
```

Doing arithmatic works fine for int's of the same type.

1. If the types are different, it <s>might or might</s> will not work .
   <s>2. If one of the types is Int, the operation works and the smallest type that will hold the result is returned.</s>
2. Change the values of i1,i2 and i3 to see this.
   note: a runtime error occurs on overflow.

For example substraction (note that the order of lhs and rhs is important here)

```
let i11 = i1 - i1
//let i12 = i1 - i2 //operator cannot be applied to types Int16 and Int32
let i13 = i1 - i3
```

<s>Inspecting the types shows that the indeed the smallest Int is returned.</s>

```
print(i11.dynamicType) //Int16
//print(i12.dynamicType) //n.a.
print(i13.dynamicType)//Int16
```

<s>*Intermezzo:
How does Apple implement this? Do they convert everything to Int, do the operation and then castdown? How do they determine the smallest Type?*</s> *See Martin's comment*

If we need a collection of these Int's, we will run into trouble.

```
let int = [i1,i2,i3] // ambiguous without more context
let int : [Int] = [i1,i2,i3] // cannot convert Int16 to Int
```

And at this point we search stackoverflow and decide to use a DataType protocol.

```
extension Int16 : DataType{}
extension Int32 : DataType{}
extension Int   : DataType{}
```

Which will allows us to have an array,

```
//let all = [i1,i2,i3]  // type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

if we specify the element type explicitly.

```
let int : [DataType] = [i1,i2,i3] 
print(int.dynamicType) //[DataType]
```

Now we want to compute something
var total : DataType = 0

```
print(total.dynamicType) //Int
//int.reduce(total) { $0 - $1 } //operator cannot be applied to types _ and DataType
```

Not sure what _ is or should or could be. So what about this?

```
for element in int
{
    total = total - element //operator cannot be applied to types DataType and DataType
}
```

Ok, so we overload the function for two DataTypes

```
func - (lhs: DataType, rhs: DataType) -> DataType
{
    print("substract: \(lhs) - \(rhs)")
//  return lhs - rhs //RECURSION: this is going to take forever (don't remove the comments here)

    //ok, so cast to Int. But what if our DataType is not an Int, but something crazy like a String or our custom DataType (e.g. complex number)? 
    //we can do double dispatch
    rhs.substract(lhs)
}
```

After searching some more, we find out about double dispatch. With double dispatch we can make the types more specific.

To do so we start by extending Int.

```
extension Int : DataType
{
    func substract(lhs: DataType) -> DataType
    {
        //now we know the rhs (i.e. self) is an Int
        return lhs.substract(self) //note that we "substract" lhs from rhs 
    }

    func substract(rhs: Int) -> DataType
    {
        //now we know both lhs and rhs are Int's
        return lhs - rhs //and this will use the builtin Swift function
    }
}
```

Now we can safely implement our global function

```
 func - (lhs: DataType, rhs: DataType) -> DataType
 {
    rhs.substract(lhs) //note that we "substract" lhs from rhs
 }
```

and define our protocol

```
Protocol DataType
{
    func substact(lhs: DataType, rhs: DataType) -> DataType
    func substact(lhs: DataType, rhs: Int16) -> DataType
    func substact(lhs: DataType, rhs: Int32) -> DataType
    func substact(lhs: DataType, rhs: Int) -> DataType
}
```

However now we have to add a function to the protocol for every conceivable type that conforms to DataType.
And we have to implement all of those functions as well for every type that conforms to DataType.

Moreover we can't use generics because that would again lead to recursion. The types aren't changed.

And if we have two regular Int's that just happen to have a DataType signature:

```
let d1 : DataType = 6
let d2 : DataType = 8

let d12 = d1 - d2
```

then double dispatch will also be used even though the builtin function would be more efficient. After all that would skip two function calls.

So my question, in addition to those from the intermezzo, is this: is there a better way to accomplish this? One that wouldn't need a bloated protocol (a function for every supported type) and that wouldn't unnecessarily sidestep the built-in swift functions.

Is Apple using double dispatch to add the Int and Int16 values (see above)?

**edit1** Added linethrough's (see Martin's comment)

**edit2**
Swift has an IntegerArithmatic protocol that inherits from _IntegerArithmatic.

_IntegerArithmatic defines functions like these which should not be used directly since they are an implementation detail (see header file).

```
func isEqual(to  other: Self) -> Bool
```

However the FloatingPoint protocol has no such distinction and both 'isEqual' and '==' functions are declared directly in the FloatingPoint protocol. Why the difference?

Comment: Swift does not allow arithmetic operations between different integer type. `let i13 = i1 - i3` compiles just by chance (or by bad luck) because `Int16.Stride` is `Int`.

Comment: I was indeed surprised that one worked and the other one didn't.

Comment: Remains the (main) issue of double dispatch and whether this is a good approach or if there is something better.